# if $a , b$ are positive numbers such that $a + b = 1$ prove that for all $x$ $ae^{\frac{x}{a}} + be^{-\frac{x}{b}} \le e^{\frac{x^2}{8a^2b^2}}$

Tags: inequalities, exponential-sums

I am working to prove the following inequality, however I have not reached to any definite solutions. I would be so thankful if anyone could help me prove this inequality or at least give me some hints and ideas to prove this inequality:

if $a , b$  are positive numbers such that $a + b = 1$ prove that for all $x$

$ae^{\frac{x}{a}} + be^{-\frac{x}{b}} \le e^{\frac{x^2}{8a^2b^2}}$

one of my friends told me to use the Taylor series of the two exponents on the left side of the inequality but I did not reach to the proper solution. Moreover, I chose to use the weighted arithmetic mean of the two exponents on the left side of the inequality but I did not reach to the solution either!!!

Please help me

Comment: You already asked over at Mathematics StackExchange (twice). Give it a week, and please: don't cross-post without linking, at every SE site where you ask, to every other SE site where you ask.

Comment: @ToddTrimble sure thanks a lot, the answer to this questions is very vital for me therefore I thought it might be helpful to post the same question in different places. Anyway, from now on I would definitely give a link of the previous places where I posted this question.

Comment: If anyone wants to have a crack at this, here's the MSE link: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1978987/prove-that-for-all-x-ae-fracxa-be-fracxb-leq-e-fracx28 I see Fedor Petrov has given an answer, but it seems not to be easy...

Comment: This is a well-known problem, also posed on dxdy forum. Why to ban it immediately for no reason at all? Let start a company to ban a band of unprofessional banners!

Comment: @Sergei Could you give the link to where it is posted at dxdy? Is it a contest problem?

Comment: @Sergei, Thanks a lot for your comment. I would also deeply appreciate it if you could share the link to where this question is posted at dxdy.

Comment: Here posted by "arqady" (Arqady Rosenberg): http://dxdy.ru/topic112404.html . No comments still! Difficuilt "schtuchka"!

Comment: Here is the link where @Fedor Petrov gave an answer to the inequality mentioned above LINK: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1978987/prove-that-for-all-x-ae-fracxa-be-fracxb-leq-e-fracx28

Comment: Is it complete?

Comment: @Sergei yes it is, Is there any thing vague about the question?